# Как получить данные возвращаемые методом в ASP.Net MVC 4 приложении?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Разбираюсь с MVC 4 приложением, все методы возвращают ActionResult, вот собственно код метода Детали:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    return View(db.GetItem(id));
}
```

В этом методе делаю выборку нужной мне записи и передаю в представление, так вот вопрос, каким способом я могу перехватить мою запись с помощью Jquery, когда страницу вернет сервер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Идея следующая.

Сериализуем модель в формат *JSON* и поместим в элемент `<script>` во *View*

```
<script type="text/json" id="model">
    @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
</script>
```

[`Json.Encode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode.aspx)
преобразует объект в строку в формате *JSON*
[`Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg480740.aspx)
вернет строку без экранирования специальных символов *HTML*

Далее пишем обработчик *jQuery*, который будет отрабатывать на клиенте после загрузки страницы.

```
$(function(){
    var json = $('#model').text();  // извлекаем текст из элемента `script`
    var model = JSON.parse(json);   // преобразуем строку в формате JSON в объект
});
```

---

Полный рабочий пример на [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hKnwwC).